# Looping through a string value based on occurrences of a value and parsing out values into new rows

Tags: excel, xml, vba, for-loop

So I'm trying to do something a little bit complex but am not sure how to tackle it as I'm very new to VBA coding syntax (but intermediately experienced in other programming languages)

Basically, I am trying to parse through this text:

```
<Step>

    <Description>

        This is a description

    </Description>

    <Validation>

        This is how we validate

    </Validation>

</Step>

<Step>

    <Description>

        This is another description.

    </Description>

    <Validation>

        And this is another validation.

    </Validation>

</Step>
```

And it's parsed based on the key tokens that begin and end the text. So, the beginning statements are brackets followed by the field descriptor and they are thus closed by the brackets and a forward slash.

Right now, I'm using a UDF called Supermid (taken from [this website](https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/easily-extract-text-between-two-strings-with-vba/)) that returns the values between two given words (in this case, the beginning and end tokens I just described).
So if the text above is in Cell A1, `Supermid(A1, "<Validation>","</Validation>")`would return "This is how we validate.".

I'm running through a problem where I want to loop through the above text, and parse it seperately for each `<Step> </Step>` instance.

So because there are two `<Steps>` encapsulating the description token and the validation token, i'd like to seperate them.

So it would look a little something like this:

```
Step 1  This is a description   This is how we validate
Step 2  This is another description And this is another validation
```

Essentially I want to loop through the entire field, and each  that is detected is treated as it's own entity that's iterated upon and is parsed out accordingly to respective columns (col B for the description, col C for the Validation)

I'm thinking the pseudo code would look something like this if i'm incorporating supermid and the value I want to parse is in Cell A1:

```
For i = 0; i < Steps; i++:
     Range("C1").Formula = "=supermid($A1, ""<Feature Description>"", ""</Feature Description>"")"
     Range("D1").Formula = "=supermid($A1, ""<Feature Validation>"", ""</Feature Validation>"")"]
     Range("B1").Formula = ""Step" & i" //this is to clarify which step number it is
```

My main issue is converting this psuedo code to VBA syntax, as I've never worked with it to a deep extent and i'm learning as I go. 
I'm thinking I have to count the occurrences of Beginning `<Step>`, store that in a Long, and use that as my iterator for 'i'.

The biggest issue is separating the parsed text into new rows for each iteration and I'm not sure how to count the number of Steps that occur in a string value and separate them accordingly.

Is there a way to iterate the Cell number for each loop iteration? And how do I reference that 'i' value when displaying the Steps?

If anyone can point me to the right direction, it would be HUGELY appreciated!

Thank you!!!

Comment: This looks like XML, so it seems like you'd be better off using the standard approaches for working with XML, rather than using a string-based approach?

Comment: to @TimWilliams comment, use the [XML DOM Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757828(v%3Dvs.85)) in excel. You can loop through nodes very easily with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use Excel's built-in functions.  *(If you don't have them, you can program something similar in VBA).*

- I pasted your document into `A1:A16` (removing the extraneous line feeds).
- I turned it into a valid XML document by "wrapping" it in two other tokens `<t></t>`
- XPATH:  `//Step[1]/*` returns all the children of Step #1
- I then used the `FILTERXML` function to extract each **Step** using an `XPath` expression and joined the results with the `TEXTJOIN` function.

---

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t>" &TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,$A$1:$A$16)& "</t>","//Step[" & ROWS($1:1)&"]/*")),"")
```

The `ROWS` function, when dragged down, will generate the **Step** number to extract. The `IFERROR` function will return a null string when you have returned all of the Steps

The formula above is an **array** formula.  Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Tester()

    'in your VBProject, add a reference to:
    '  "Microsoft XML v6.0"

    Dim steps As Object, step As Object, i As Long
    Dim oXMLDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xmlData

    'XML needs a root element
    xmlData = "<?xml version=""1.0""?><data>" & ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value & "</data>"

    oXMLDoc.LoadXML xmlData
    oXMLDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    Set steps = oXMLDoc.SelectNodes("//data/Step")
    For Each step In steps
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print "****** Step" & i
        Debug.Print "Description", step.SelectSingleNode("Description").nodeTypedValue
        Debug.Print "Validation", step.SelectSingleNode("Validation").nodeTypedValue
    Next step

End Sub
```

I'm storing your data in a worksheet cell, but it could come from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

So I opted not to go the XML route (as that wasn't my intention when using those types of tags, it was more just a convention I was familiar with in HTML) and instead just went a sorely VBA route.

Here's what I came up with:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Jdescription As String
Dim steps As Integer
Dim name, desc, valid As Integer
Dim newDescription As String
name = 1
desc = 1
valid = 1

Set rng = Sheets("Scratch2").Range("A1:A" & LastRowDescription)
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    Jdescription = cell.Value
    steps = (Len(Jdescription) - Len(Replace(Jdescription, "<Step>", ""))) / Len("<Step>")
    For i = 1 To steps
         newDescription = Left(Jdescription, 7 + InStr(Jdescription, "</Step>"))
         Sheets("Scratch2").Cells(name, 2).Value = "Step " & i
         name = name + 1
         Sheets("Scratch2").Cells(desc, 3).Value = SuperMid(newDescription, "<Description>", "</Description>")
         desc = desc + 1
         Sheets("Scratch2").Cells(valid, 4).Value = SuperMid(newDescription, "<Validation>", "</Validation>")
         valid = valid + 1
         Jdescription = Replace(Jdescription, newDescription, "")
    Next i
Next cell
```